# Propagation Delay due to Ferrite Bead

Tags: inductor, waveform, ferrite-bead

When I pass a 33MHz 'Square Wave' through 3 ferrite beads connected in series, 742792606 (from Wurth), I see that the output wave turns 'Sine' in form. Also there is a delay as it propagates through the beads (close to 8nS) and it reaches the destination late.

1. How does the Inductor (ferrite bead) convert square wave to sine wave?
2. What parameters of the FB contribute to the propagation delay? What is the relation between delay and inductance?

Your response will help me to understand the nature of ferrite beads better, so thanks much!

Comment: You should really read about FFT an how signals are made up out of their frequency contents and what filters really are and do to those signals. You are basically asking for the contents of a good book as the asnwer.

Comment: On its own it can't do what you say so please show a circuit of your test set-up and include details of measurement devices and signal generators etc..

Comment: @andy aka: the signal source is imx processor, the probe used is tektronix p5050b (500MHz). circuit is simple, 3 ferrite beads in series on the clock line, I m probing at the end of 3rd ferrite bead.

Comment: And the load after the 3rd FB is.......??????

Answer (score 4):

Ferrite beads are essentially small inductors.  There is parasitic capacitance in the device pins and traces.  Together with the three ferrites the stray capacitance is probably forming a 6th order low pass LC filter.

The square wave is being rounded because the higher frequency terms are being removed by the filter.

The propagation delay you are seeing is partially from the phase delay of that filter.  Additionally if the ferrite beads lengthen the path of the signal via internal wire windings then you can expect at a minimum of 1ns/ft of  propagation delay from the internal wire length (and probably multiple times that due to the high permeability within the ferrites).

Comment: pls help me to understand why '6th' order LC filter is formed, how did you conclude the order?

Comment: There is one inductance for each bead.  And three sets of stray capacitances.  The first stray capacitance is between the first two beads, the second capacitance is between the second and third bead, and the third capacitance is between the third bead and the clocks destination.  Each capacitor and inductor pair forms a second order low pass filter.  The three filters cascaded together form a 6th order filter.